# Django DRF, how to properly register custom URL patterns with DRF actions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## Background

I have a ModelViewSet that defines several custom actions. I am using the default router in my `urls.py` to register the URLs. Right now, my views use the default created routes like `^images/$`, `^images/{pk}/$`.

In order for users to use the API using resource names with which they are familiar, I have adapted the viewset to accept multiple parameters from the URL, using the [MultipleFieldLookupMixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins) strategy described in the docs to allow for the pattern `images/{registry_host}/{repository_name}/{tag_name}`.

I've created the `get_object` method in my viewset like so:

```py
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def get_object(self):
        special_lookup_kwargs = ['registry_host', 'repository_name', 'tag_name']
        if all(arg in self.kwargs for arg in special_lookup_kwargs):
            # detected the custom URL pattern; return the specified object
            return Image.objects.from_special_lookup(**self.kwargs)
        else: # must have received pk instead; delegate to superclass
            return super().get_object()
```

I've also added a new URL path pattern for this:

urls.py

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'images', views.ImageViewSet)
# register other viewsets
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('images/<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>/<str:tag_name>', views.ImageViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve',})),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

## Problem

The above all works as intended, however, I also have some extra `actions` in this model viewset:

```py
    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def bases(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def another_action(...):
        ... # and so on
```

With the default patterns registered by DRF, I could go to `images/{pk}/<action>` (like `images/{pk}/bases`) to trigger the extra action methods. However I cannot do this for `images/{registry_host}/{repository_name}/{tag_name}/<action>`. This is somewhat expected because I never registered any such URL and there's no reasonable way DRF could know about this.

I'm *guessing* that I can add all these paths manually with an appropriate arguments to `path(...)` but I'm not sure what that would be.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('.../myaction', ???)
]
```

## Questions

As a primary question, how do I add the actions for my URL?

However, I would like to avoid having to add new URLS every time a new `@action()` is added to the view. Ideally, I would like these to be registered automatically under the default path `images/{pk}/<action>` as well as `images/{registry_host}/{repository_name}/{tag_name}/<action>`.

As a secondary question, what is the appropriate way to achieve this automatically? My *guess* is perhaps a custom router. However, it's unclear to me how I would implement adding these additional routes for all extra (detail) actions.

Using django/drf 3.2

Answer (score 2):

Another approach I see is to (ab)use `url_path` with kwargs like:

```py
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], url_path='<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>)/<str:tag_name>/bases')
    def bases_special_lookup(...):
        # detail=False to remove <pk>

    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def bases(...):
        ...

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], url_path='<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>)/<str:tag_name>')
    def retrieve_special_lookup(...):
        # detail=False to remove <pk>

    def retrieve(...):
        ...
```

This will create these urls:

```
images/<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>/<str:tag_name>/bases
images/<pk>/bases
images/<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>/<str:tag_name>
images/<pk>
```

Comment: Yes, this crossed my mind and seems like a workable solution. Ideally, I’d also like to keep the original URLs as well and have the ability to have multiple patterns to hit the same object detail with a small handful of different URL patterns  I wonder if this action decorator could somehow be extended to provide multiple patterns.

Comment: I was looking at that as well but it seems a lot of work since you also need to work on the viewset and router   Also considering that extending `@action` will not be enough to support this for the default created routes

Comment: Yeah, and unfortunately it seems the router only accepts regex paths, too, so using `url_path='<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>)/<str:tag_name>'` won't quite work, either. I haven't been able to get an equivalent regex path, partly because consuming the `/` correctly in the `path:` argument is tricky. Rewriting a router to do anything other than regex seems impractical, unfortunately. So, for now, I'm just registering these all manually in my `urls.py` 

Comment: Surprised it didn't work. That output I shared was from `show_urls` and I was expecting that can match and be sent as kwargs on the view

Comment: Problem is the type is that when registered, it's a regex type (`re_path`) of URL, not a `path` type. So the path gets interpreted as a literal regex pattern.

Comment: I see. Good to know!

Comment: It seems that Django's `urls.path` uses the same private `_path` function, but with a `RoutePattern` instead of `RegexPattern` but it seems that `RoutePattern` converts ultimately to regex anyhow through a private `_route_to_regex` function. So, it may be possible to make a router subclass that accepts a regular route pattern, but, probably a bit too much work for me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably a better way of doing this, but you could try something like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'images', views.ImageViewSet)
# register other viewsets
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('images/<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>/<str:tag_name>', views.ImageViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve',})),
    path('images/<str:registry_host>/<path:repository_name>/<str:tag_name>/<str:action>', views.ImageViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve',})),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

and then in your viewset:

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def get_object(self):
        special_lookup_kwargs = ['registry_host', 'repository_name', 'tag_name']
        if all(arg in self.kwargs for arg in special_lookup_kwargs):
            action = getattr(self, self.kwargs.pop('action', ''), None)
            if action:
                #not sure what your action is returning so you may not want to return this
                return action(self.request)
            # detected the custom URL pattern; return the specified object
            return Image.objects.from_special_lookup(**self.kwargs)
        else: # must have received pk instead; delegate to superclass
            return super().get_object()
```

Comment: This is a pretty interesting thought! Though, unfortunately I think the mechanism that calls `get_object` comes _from_ the view routed. For example, all the actions actually call `self.get_object` so in this case, that would lead to infinite recursion. But maybe I can override the dispatch method to a similar effect,

Comment: Would it cause recursion? I am popping the action from self.kwargs so it will be removed by the time your actions call the `get_object` function. And if you hit the first URL it wont have an action kwarg so it should be safe to use with either URL. I might be missing something though as I haven't tried this locally :). I'm interested to see what you come up with.

Comment: I think the important problem is that the detail actions return _response_ objects. `get_object` should return a model object. In order to return a response, an action will at some point call `get_object`, which is supposed to return an instance of the model. In the above case it seems `get_object` would return a response by calling `action()`, when it should return a model instance instead. Putting the recursion aside, I think the `get_object` method like this just wouldn't return what is expected: a response. Though, I think there may be a variation of this solution that might be workable.